How to forcely load data in q-tree while in lazy-load mode
I'm using Quasar q-tree component in the lazy-mode.

when I firstly click the triangle icon of one leaf node, it can trigger the event @lazy-load, and fetch data from the server and give the result data into q-tree using done function in the event detail data
After that, I collapse the same node, and expand it for the secondary time
The children nodes expanded directly, not trigger the @lazy-load event

I known maybe because the q-tree has the returned data internally, but in my case, I need to fetch data from server while expanding the node every time.
Also trigger @lazy-load event forcely while expanding the node every time
If Quasar q-tree component support this feature? and How should I do?
Thank you for any advice sincerely!!
